# How to find frequencies of multiple ID's from one column by year and plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, frequency, analysis

I have a df that looks like

| ID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| Nation, Nation - NA, Economy, Economy - Asia | 2008 |
| Economy, Economy - EU, State, Nation | 2009 |

I would like to extract the frequencies of the ID's so that it looks like

| Nation | Economy | State | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 2008 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2009 |

For ID's that have hyphens like "Economy - EU", I am only interested in counting this as a frequency of "Economy"

My end goal is to plot this df by year with the frequency counts of different ID's in the same plot. So for example, "State" would be a green dot in 2008, "Nation" would be a red dot in 2008, and "Economy" would be a blue dot in 2008.

If the second df is not a good way to do this, I am also open to suggestions! That was just my first thought on how to start this.

I will this post as a separate question if this is not appropriate, but my next question is how to plot the frequencies of the second df by year, as mentioned above?

Thank you!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. You can ask question about plotting separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the data into different rows using `separate_rows` splitting on a comma (`,`). Separate the value after `-` in a different column and calculate occurrence of `ID` value in each `Year` and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(ID, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  separate(ID, c('ID', 'Value'), sep = '\\s*-\\s*',fill = 'right') %>%
  count(Year, ID) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

#   Year Economy Nation State
#  <int>   <int>  <int> <int>
#1  2008       2      2     0
#2  2009       2      1     1
```

You can also reduce the code by using `janitor::tabyl`.

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(ID, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  separate(ID, c('ID', 'Value'), sep = '\\s*-\\s*',fill = 'right') %>%
  janitor::tabyl(Year, ID)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("Nation, Nation - NA, Economy, Economy - Asia", 
"Economy, Economy - EU, State, Nation"), Year = 2008:2009), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Wow, amazing! It looks perfect except for a couple things. It looks like some of the ID's were not counted? I get this error for both scripts you provided

"Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 23 rows [9, 14, 16, 17, 36, 37, 41, 45, 48, 57, 70, 71, 84, 86, 94, 132, 138, 178, 188, 218, ...]."

And some of the columns are duplicated. So for example, there are two columns for "Nations" and both columns have different frequencies.

Would you be able to help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it would be difficult to help without an example of where it fails. I have shared data in a reproducible format below my answer using which it works as expected. The columns would not be duplicated but I think they must have whitespace around them. After `separate` try adding `%>% ..mutate(ID = trimws(ID)) %>% count..` to remove whitespace.

Comment: mutate(ID = trimws(ID)), this worked and combined the duplicated columns! 
I will try to figure out the discarded row thing, but thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

1. We could use `str_count` to count the strings and summarise by `Year`
2. Bring the data in long format with `pivot_longer` for `ggplot`
3. Use `ggplot` for barchart (basic version demonstrated)

```
library(tidyverse)

# table
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(Nation = str_count(ID, "Nation"),
         Economy = str_count(ID, "Economy"),
         State = str_count(ID,"State"))

df
# preparation for plotting
df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Year,
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) 

# plot
ggplot(df1, aes(x = factor(names), y=values, fill=factor(Year), label=values)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(size = 4, position =position_dodge(1),vjust=-.5)
```

Output:

```
   Year Nation Economy State
* <dbl>  <int>   <int> <int>
1  2008      2       2     0
2  2009      1       2     1
```

plot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think [Ronak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67715572/2884859) has nailed it completely, but as you have mentioned in question that your ultimate goal is to plot, I think there is no need to `pivot_wider`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(ID = c("Nation, Nation - NA, Economy, Economy - Asia", 
                            "Economy, Economy - EU, State, Nation"), Year = 2008:2009), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df %>%
  separate_rows(ID, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  separate(ID, c('ID', 'Value'), sep = '\\s*-\\s*',fill = 'right') %>%
  count(Year, ID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= as.factor(Year), y = n, color = ID)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

OR

```r
df %>%
  separate_rows(ID, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  separate(ID, c('ID', 'Value'), sep = '\\s*-\\s*',fill = 'right') %>%
  count(Year, ID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= as.factor(Year), y = n, color = ID, label = paste(ID, n, sep = '-'))) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(size = 2, position =position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>